# How to stop my page from scrolling up when i click on custom control of asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have asp.net custom control like treecontrol, when I scroll down the page and click on any item from that control, it causes page scroll up like loaded for first time.

Comment: Can you post the treecontrol source (markup or "as rendered" by the .Net engine)?

Answer (score 0):

probably some controls refresh, use AutoPostBack="false" if can

Comment: thnx for the replay,bt its not causing postback,i hv chked it, any other posibilities??

Comment: how to track, why the page causes scrolling when any event occured @UI side?

Comment: & this isseu I noticed only in FF, any specific setting M I missing??

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this was ever answered or resolved though, after stumbling upon a similar issue, i found the following resolution:

Used the following line of code in my Site.Master.cs, Page_load()

Page.MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack = True

worked for me!
Hope this helps.

source: http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t121257-scroll-in-asp-net-postback.html